# Package a forked composer through packagist

Tags: php, git, composer-php, fork

I want to fork this [Git repo](https://github.com/beyondcode/expose) and submit a private package through [Packagist](https://packagist.org).

I forked the package, cloned it on my local machine, and changed a couple of lines without adding or installing any extra dependencies. Super vanilla.

Now comes the confusing part: I’m not sure what to do with `composer.json`.

I edit my package name at the top of `composer.json` and submit it to Packagist. However, when I try to build it, it says that the build is not a stable version.

Here's my forked [git repo](https://github.com/dennisong45/expose)

The `composer.json` from the Git repo have the following.
(Just a shorten version of the `composer.json`.)

```json
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3.0",
    "ext-json": "*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "cboden/ratchet": "^0.4.2",
    
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/seankndy/reactphp-sqlite"
        }
```

From the guide in a YouTube video that I saw, usually, they have the Git repo in the `require` dictionary.

Which steps am I missing? Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Did you pushed your local changes to your fork on GitHub?

Comment: Hi @rob006. Yes i did.